# 'Grep'ing the IP out of a finger command on linux

Tags: grep, regex, finger

I am using ssh to access another machine and require the IP from which I am sshing from. Finger gives this, but I don't know how to isolate this from the information given. So far I have:

```
finger | grep $USER
```

Which produces:

```
jonno     Jonathan Mackenzie   pts/9          Sep 21 16:23 (111.111.111.111)
```

What is the last grep required to isolate the IP address (i changed it here for security reasons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
finger | grep $USER | egrep -o "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Answer (score 4):

When you `ssh` somewhere a few environment variables are set:

```
SSH_CLIENT 
SSH_TTY  
SSH_CONNECTION
```

do take a look at them, they are quite useful.